# Variations of transformation of inversion?

Tags: geometry, transformation

Is there a transformation analogous to [inversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversive_geometry), that is based on something other than circle (or sphere in higher dimensions), and has some interesting properties or applications?

[image]

The motivation for my question is sheer curiosity, and so far I didn't find any example of what I mentioned.

Comment: You can define an *inversion* about any kind of star-shaped curve around some $c$. (Star-shaped here means that the curv is closed, and every line from $c$ to a point on the curve lies within the area enclosed by the curve).

Comment: Right, but is circle inversion the only one that preserves angles? Or maps circles to circles?

Comment: Well, inversion about an arbitrary star-shaped curve would preserve scaled version of *that* curve I think. As for angels - not sure, my geometric intuition is leaving me there ;-)